# Rails-Jquery: Updating a Database Field on a click event

Tags: jquery, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I am new to Rails/Jquery and am really struggling.

What I want to do is change several fields in my database from null to true when a user clicks on a button (without navigating away from the current page). I know I need to use Ajax in some way or another, but am not sure how. I have been struggling for about 2 hours now and would love it if someone could even point me in the right direction.

Stackoverflow, you are my only hope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote an answer responding to a question similar to yours not long ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6643671/rails-how-to-get-jquery-to-update-a-database-column-after-a-click/6643771#6643771).  But basically what you have are 3 parts:

- Your view that makes the AJAX request
- Your controller that handles the AJAX request
- and your .js.erb file that your controller will render

In your view, you will have something like

```
<%= button_to "Click me!", :action => "some_action", :remote => true %>
```

Which will send an AJAX request back to the server, in which you need to handle in your controller

```
def some_actoin
    // Update your database here
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js { render 'somepartial' }
    end
end
```

Then you will have a 'somepartial.js.erb' file that contains the code (in your case I don't know if this file needs to contain anything) that updates your DOM.

Read [this](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/06/unobtrusive-javascript-in-rails-3/) for a very good explanation of AJAX and Rails3.  Good luck.

Comment: This totally covers it; but you (Spencer) should feel free to ask questions pertaining to your specific case as there are a plethora of ways to go about this.

Comment: I guess the part I am having trouble with is the some action part. Do I need to create root the corresponds with this action? I have used this method for a create action and got it to work. However, I have never used it just for something arbitrary.